# Python version problem in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, version

When I write `print("Hello", "world")` the output should be `Hello world`, however what I am getting is `('Hello', 'world')` I understand that this has something to do with the Python version, where in python 2 the print function did not require parentheses.

I have tried changing the python version and it is displayed as python 3.10.0, I have tried using a custom path as well as looking in other forums but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: What's the result of `print(sys.executable)`? How can you confirm you have selected the python3.10? where have you got it?

Comment: I solved the problem since so if you are here to help thanks but I managed to switch versions in the end. If you have this problem yourself then here is how I did it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69833055/change-the-version-to-python-3-in-virtual-studio-code-vs-code-if-code-runner-u

Answer (score 1):

This is because, as you said, you use an old version of Python.
To find a solution, try with:

```
print("Hello " + "world")
```

The output will be:

```
>>> Hello world
```