# Change the version to Python 3 in Virtual Studio Code (VS Code) if Code Runner uses older version like python 2 (Q+A)

Tags: python, visual-studio, vscode-code-runner, coderunner

I use the extension code-runner for my VS code to run it directly in the app without a terminal and I had a problem where I had the latest version of Python installed (3.10.0) I had selected that version as my interpreter yet code-runner was running my code in python2.

Here is the solution which worked for me:

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner, I could not understand the way other solutions were explained so I hope this helps:

1. Go to your User Settings .json by opening the Command Palette with View > Command Palette or by pressing Command+Shift+P on Mac or Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows. Then search for **Preferences: Open Settings(JSON)**
2. in a new tab, once again open the command palette but this time look for
   **Preferences: Open User Settings**
3. in the 'Search settings' bar at the top search for 'Shebang'. Make sure that the box of '*Code-runner: Respect Shebang*' is not ticked.
4. go back to your .json settings file and check that the following line of code is in there:
   `"code-runner.respectShebang": false,`

if not, first reload the page, searching for **Developer: Reload window** in the command palette.

if it still isn't there you will need to add it yourself alongside all your other settings like so:
[image]

5. You will need to go again to **Preferences: Open User Settings** in the command palette and in the settings search bar look for *Code-runner: Executor Map*. If it is not in your settings.json file then you will need to press the little settings/gear icon which pops up when you hover your cursor over it and then select '*Copy Setting as JSON*'.
6. Go back to your settings.json file and paste it in there alongside all your other settings like with Shebang.
   it should look something like this:
   [image]
7. My problem was with python (but this applies to any other language). Go to the line `"python": "python -u",` and change it to `"python": "python3 -u",`.

This solved the issue for me. :)